# Problems converting PDF to BMP using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I would like to `convert` a PDF to BMP. The PDF I am talking about is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwSN0jwV9-8ZTmVWV2Y1emdOa1U/view?usp=sharing).

I use ImageMagick with the following command :

```
convert -verbose -resize 256x256 phantom-brain-ellipse.pdf phantom.bmp
```

But the result is a `phantom.bmp` file corrupted or empty file with pixel dimensions `0x0`.

The error message is :

```
"/opt/local/bin/gsx" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=/var/tmp/magick-1199-UNts2yPB9u2%d" "-f/var/tmp/magick-1199rG26g03biUuT" "-f/var/tmp/magick-1199-sNgqMmlD53M"
/var/tmp/magick-1199-UNts2yPB9u21 PNG 263x263 263x263+0+0 8-bit sRGB 54.6KB 0.010u 0:00.009
phantom-brain-ellipse.pdf PDF 263x263 263x263+0+0 16-bit sRGB 54.6KB 0.000u 0:00.000
phantom-brain-ellipse.pdf=>phantom.bmp PDF 263x263=>256x256 256x256+0+0 16-bit sRGB 262KB 0.020u 0:00.019
```

When I convert to PNG everything works fine with the same command :

```
convert -verbose -resize 256x256 phantom-brain-ellipse.pdf phantom.png
```

Any idea how to fix that ?

### Partial Solution

This command allowed me to get the right BMP :

```
convert phantom.png BMP3:phantom.bmp
```

But I don't get why it works !

Comment: Does it work without the resize?

Comment: no , negative , I get an image with size 0x0 !!

Comment: Is Ghostscript installed? IM uses Ghostscript to handle PDFs.

Comment: Yes. It is installed. I made an edit to my question. I have found a *partial solution* ...

Comment: Your partial solution seems to be involving a PNG, too, is that a typo?

Comment: No I convert my pdf first to png and then to bmp3   It worked !!

Comment: Which version(s) of Ghostscript is/are involved here? (See `gs -version` ***and*** `/opt/local/bin/gsx -version`.)

Comment: GPL Ghostscript 9.10 (2013-08-30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
convert -verbose -resize 256x256 phantom-brain-ellipse.pdf[0] BMP3:phantom.bmp
```

---

## Update/Explanation

1. PDF is a multipage format. Potentially, the input PDF has more than one page.

   ImageMagick commands can select a specific page with the naming convention `filename[i]`, where ***`i`*** is the *index* of the page. Indexing is zero-based, so `some.pdf[0]` means: *"Use page 1 of this PDF."*
2. The `SOMEFORMAT:filename` convention determines the file format for output files and overrides any file format which may be indicated by the filename suffix. So an output filename of `GIF:some.png` will create a GIF file with the (wrong) suffix `.png`.
3. The `BMP3:` is a specific version of the general BMP format. By default, `BMP:filename` or `filename.bmp` will produce version 4 of BMP. To get version 3 use `BMP3:filename.bmp`. To get version 2 use `BMP2:filename.bmp`.
4. I used `BMP3:` because you reported that it worked...

Comment: any explanation please ?

Comment: it worked ... can you explain (with references) the `[0]` and `BMP3:` ??

Comment: @OSryx: see updated answer. *(You haven't answered the question underneath your original posting!)*

Comment: sorry, I did not pay attention to that one ... any way , what is the latest version of BMP ? I choosed BMP3 because I have tried BMP2 and BMP only ? but I don't know the difference can you specify that ?

Comment: @OSryx Maybe give Kurt an upvote too for his tireless efforts helping folk out ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell of course, why not :) how about my *good* question ? :)

Comment: I haven't tried it, yet, but BMP3 specifies a 40 byte header (older version of BMP now designated BMP3). Most BMP read programs check the header length. You don't say why the BMP is corrupted, but it is probably an old reader on a new file. BMP3 gives you the old file.